# Why $\prod_p\sum_{n\geq 1}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\prod_p$?

Tags: real-analysis

Q1) Let $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{g(n)}{n^s}$ a series that converge absolutely for $\Re(s)>1$. Why $$\prod_p\sum_{i\geq 1}\frac{g(p^i)}{p^{is}}=\sum_{i\geq 1}\prod_p\frac{g(p^i)}{p^{is}}\ \ ?$$
Is it the fact that converge absolutely ? How can I show this equality ?

Q2) Does $$\sum_{i\geq 1}\sum_{j\geq 1}a_{ij}=\sum_{j\geq 1}\sum_{i\geq1}a_{ij},$$
always or we need more conditions ? And if we need more condition, what are these conditions ?

Comment: (Q1) is not right. What is $g$? (Q2) Is true if the series is absolutely convergent. That is, if $\sum_{i}\sum_{j} \left|a_{ij}\right|$ is convergent. It might not be true if it is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: If $g$ is multiplicative, then $$\prod_{p}\sum_{i\geq 1}\frac{g(p^i)}{p^{is}}=\sum_{n}\frac{g(n)}{n^s}$$ But your (Q1) Is definitely not the case.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thank you. Indeed, $g$ is multiplicative. But I don't understand why we have $\prod_p\sum_{i\geq 1}\frac{g(p^i)}{p^i}=\sum_{n}\frac{g(n)}{n^s}$ (that why I wanted to permute the product and the sum)

Comment: I was wrong about one thing - it should be $$\prod_{p}\sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{g(p^i)}{p^{is}}=\sum_{n}\frac{g(n)}{n^s}$$ The $i\geq 0$ is different.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, but how can we prove that ?

Comment: That's really not a good tone to inspire people to help you.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  I'm sincerely sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Do you feel that I missed you respect ? If yes, I apologize for this.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying some things out? For example, if $a_n$ is multiplicative then $$ (1+a_2+a_4)(1+a_3)(1+a_5+a_{25}+a_{125}) $$ will be the sum of all $a_n$ where $n=2^a 3^b 5^c$ with $2^a\in\{1,2,4\}$, $3^b\in\{1,3\}$, $5^c\in\{1,5,25,125\}$.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Andrew said, the equality is not valid in general.
$$\prod_{p\leq N}\sum_{i\geq 1}\frac{g(p^i)}{p^{si}}=\sum_{i_1\geq 1}...\sum_{i_{\pi(N)}\geq 1}\prod_{j=1}^{\pi(N)}\frac{g(p_j^{si_j})}{p_j^{i_j}},$$
whereas $$\sum_{i\geq 1}\prod_{p\leq N}\frac{g(p^i)}{p^i}$$
is something else... (just what it's written).

If $g$ is multiplicative, then 
$$\sum_{i_1\geq 1}...\sum_{i_{\pi(N)}\geq 1}\prod_{j=1}^{\pi(N)}\frac{g(p_j^{si_j})}{p_j^{si_j}}=\sum_{i_1,...,i_{\pi(N)}\geq 1}\frac{g\left(\prod_{j=1}^{\pi(N)}p_j^{i_j}\right)}{\left(\prod_{j=1}^{\pi(N)}p_{j}^{i_j}\right)^s}=\sum_{\substack{n=1\\ P(n)\leq N}}^\infty \frac{g(n)}{n^s},$$
where $P(N)=\max\{p\text{ s.t. }p\mid N\}$. Letting $N\to \infty$ we get the result.